# Nightwatch not executing in Acquia pipeline

Tags: testing, acquia-cloud

I'm trying to execute the Nightwatch test on Acquia pipeline for every PR raised

I have created a custom BLT command that executes the test cases of Nightwatch. it is executing fine locally but it fails on the pipeline.
The chrome driver is failing to connect. Below is detailed error.

[Tests/Toolbar Api Test] Test Suite

- Connecting to localhost on port 9515...

⚠ Error connecting to localhost on port 9515.

[Tests/Toolbar Test] Test Suite

- Connecting to localhost on port 9515...

⚠ Error connecting to localhost on port 9515.

---

Chromedriver is working well locally on Lando based project, but it can't connect while executing in the pipeline thus resulting in an error, Can anyone help?

Or is there any better approach to execute the Nightwatch test case on the pipeline?

Comment: Is this setup documented by Acquia as working? Are customers allowed to run servers (for example, on port 9515) on any given port?

Comment: @cilefen No, there is no document available by Acquia, Also I have used the default port assigned to the chrome driver. I can't find any document detailing port no. to be used.

Comment: You can choose other ports, see https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/2115, but ultimately you must contact Acquia support to determine which ports, if any, you may use.